# Assign permission in an entire directory inside Amazon S3 Bucket (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS SDK + PHP + Symfony2.

Is there a way to assign public-read permission to an entire directory that I've just uploaded to an Amazon S3 Bucket?

The code I normally use to assign a public-read permission is:

```
$this->s3->putObjectAcl(
    array(
        'Bucket' => $this->bucketName,
        'Key' => $destinationPath,
        'ACL' => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ
    )
);
```

But it doesn't work if $destinationPath is a directory. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: you should read about bucket policies of AWS S3.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

As *urfusion* mentioned, what you're looking for is a [Bucket Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

Here's an example policy you might use :

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```